# CAD API Programming - can't save modifications by SendStringToExecute

Tags: c#, api, autocad

CAD Masters,
I have the following code (that is mostly the same in AutoCAD), its used to simply purge the document in AutoCAD/ZWCAD:

```
Document zcDoc = Application.DocumentManager.Open(FileName, false);
zcDoc.SendStringToExecute("_-PURGE All *\nNo\n", true, false, true);
```

When it executes and I don't close the drawing programmatically, it works like a charm.
But if I run it and place a

```
zcDoc.CloseAndSave(FileName); //As the command says, it saves and close the doc
```

after, it doesn't. If I make some other modifications to the drawing before the CloseAndSave, they get saved, except changes made by .SendStringToExecute(), doesn't matter the string or command I use.

Is there anything special with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, SendStringToExecute is special. It places the string into a queue which will be executed when AutoCAD goes to fetch input again. This can be when a command you've called needs more input, or what i feel like whats happening in your case, is that it happens after your current command is done.

So, to do what you want, you probably will have to create another command that you can place at the end of your SendStringToExecute that will call the CloseAndSave.